# Is it wrong to edit your own old answer to reflect changes in the technology when another user's answer already does this?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers

So I have a slight ethical issue.

A few years ago, I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659845/swift-how-to-get-the-indexpath-row-when-a-button-in-a-cell-is-tapped/29792963#29792963) question with what I believed at the time to be a good answer. I had just started out in my field (iOS Development) at the time and was chuffed that I was able to assist another developer so early into my own career.

As my career progressed and my knowledge grew, I became more aware of the pitfalls of using an approach such as the one I suggested in my answer. This was also pointed out by a couple of other users who suggested better approaches in alternative answers.

Unfortunately, most people who visit an SO question usually grab the answer with the most upvotes (generally new users/programmers), which is mine, given that it's been there the longest, meaning that they are potentially setting themselves up for said pitfalls they could avoid by simply taking another answer.

This seemed like madness to me, so I edited my **original** answer to explain the pitfalls of the approach and suggest my new favourite alternative approach. I made sure to suggest that the reader scrolls down in the thread and browse the host of suggestions from different users, as most of them are valid.

Now it should be noted that this isn't about reputation at this stage; it's a case of 'my answer is what 80% of people will take and I want their code to be solid'. That said, others in the thread suggested **the same thing I edited into my answer, first**. Does that mean I'm capitalising on their efforts unfairly?

This is where my problem lies. I'm torn between the dilemma of potentially absolving others of well deserved reputation, and knowingly allowing users to use potentially unpredictable code. I considered straight up deleting my answer, but I think it serves as a valuable lesson, particularly for new developers, as to why approaches such as that are not best.

Would love to hear the community's thoughts on this one.

Comment: TL;DR; no it's not wrong. Happy editing!

Comment: I wouldn't consider it an obsolete answer as such, as it's still a valid approach today, just a poor one. It was more a case of my developer knowledge growing and subsequently learning that it was a poor approach. Glad editing old answers in this way is considered acceptable, though.

Comment: I would still say the same answer holds true. It's prefectly valid to edit your answer to say "Hey this works but method B is the preferred way to do it." Personally I'd up-vote the other user too.